# Bernoulli generating function and cotangent

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, bernoulli-numbers

May I ask for a little help in solving a problem about Bernoulli number generating function?

Bernoulli number generating function is given by: $$f(z):=\begin{cases}
\frac{z}{e^{z}-1} & z \in D_{2\pi}(0)\\ 
1& z=0
\end{cases}$$

I have to show that $$f(z)+\frac{z}{2}=\frac{z}{2i} \cot\left( \frac{z}{2i} \right).$$

Good, I have shown that this function is even and it holds $$f(z)+\frac{z}{2}=\left ( \frac{z}{2} \right )\frac{e^{z}+1}{e^{z}-1}=\left(\frac{z}{2}\right )\frac{{e^\frac{z}{2}}+e^{\frac{-z}{2}} }{e^{\frac{z}{2}}-e^{\frac{-z}{2}}},$$ but what else I can do, I don't know...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to express $\sin$ and $\cos$ in exponentials, and you'll see the remaining fraction is what you are looking for.